# use jQuery to identify if contents are unique and then style

Tags: jquery, filter, unique

On a page full of divs i need to identify if the contents of a div are unique and if so apply style to it, probably hide.

My problem is that I need to check through a list of divs with the same class and check the text content against another list of divs with the same class;

for example if I have a div with the class of "picker" I need to hide that div if its text content isn't in a list of divs with the class "fruits".

I have tried jQuery unique, and filter and I can't get close.

I have an example set up on fiddle to explain the problem, based on that fiddle "how do i hide the div that contains "cherry" based on the fact that no other divs contain "cherry"?"

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/jn0vLz1q/

```
<div class="picker">
Apple
</div>
<div class="picker">
Banana
</div>
<div class="picker">
Cherry
</div>


<div class="fruits">
Apple
</div>
<div class="fruits">
Banana
</div>
<div class="fruits"> 
Apple
</div>
<div class="fruits">
Banana
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of a div by using `.html()` function, like this:

```
$(".left div").each(function(){
    var bool = true;
    var selected = $(this);
    $(".left div").not(selected).each(function(){
        if(selected.html() == $(this).html()){
            bool = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(bool == false){
        console.log(selected.html() + "not unique");
    }else{
        console.log(selected.html() + "unique");
    }
});
$(".right div").each(function(){
    var bool = true;
    var selected = $(this);
    $(".right div").not(selected).each(function(){
        if(selected.html() == $(this).html()){
            bool = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(bool == false){
        console.log(selected.html() + "not unique");
    }else{
        console.log(selected.html() + "unique");
    }
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn0vLz1q/1/)..